# The closure of a set in the uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis

I just took my qualifying exam on Analysis, there was a question which I still do not have any solution for it. Here is the problem:$\\$

Let $A:=\operatorname{span}\{x^n(1-x): n\geq{1}\}\subset C[0,1]$. Describe its closure in the uniform norm.

I know the definition of closure and I guess by uniform norm, they mean supremum norm. Any hints or comments?

Comment: Right, "uniform norm" is another term for the supremum norm. It defines the topology of uniform convergence, which may be related to the name. Do you know the Weierstraß approximation theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I do know. I guess I  got the point... Is the closure whole space $C[0,1]$?

Comment: For $x$ very close to $0$, the second factor $(1-x)$ is nearly $1$, so limits of finite linear combinations of these for $x$ near $0$ should look a lot like power series in $x$.  Power series converge uniformly on compact subsets of their domain of convergence.  I suppose you'd want to consider series whose radius of convergence is at least $1$.  But this comment is very remote from the end of the matter. $\qquad$

Comment: @TrevorNorton: I just realized this is an application of Stone-Weierstraß theorem...

Comment: @Mary I'd say yes, with a twist: any function $f\in A$ must satisfy $f(0)=f(1)=\dots$, so any limit of a sequence of functions in $A$ (whether it be uniform or even pointwise) must also...

Comment: @ClementC: That's right. I did not think about Stone-Weierstraß thm at all. Now I got the point. Thanks!